What am I doing wrong in this volume integral (solid torus)?
I was solving an exercise from Stewart's Calculus (8th edition, Ex. 6.3.46, page 455) in which I had to use cylindrical shells to find the volume of a solid torus of radii $r$ and $R$, as shown below.

Due to my inexperience, I drew the circle in the center of the plane in order to rotate the rectangles around the axis $x = R$. In this way, the circumference of the shell is $2\pi(R-x)$, the height is $2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ and the thickness is $\Delta x$.

Therefore, I supposed that the integral
$$
\int_{-r}^{r} 4\pi(R-x)\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,dx 
$$
would help me to find the volume of the torus.
However, I did the mathematical development (as shown below) but it gave me the expression
$$
2\pi^2Rr^2 - \tfrac83\pi r^3, 
$$
while the true answer is $2\pi^2Rr^2$.
I can't find my mistake so far, I would be so grateful if you can help me to find it. Thank you very much in advance! (Sorry for my English; I used a translator.)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Your mistake is right at the beginning where you write
$$
\int_{-r}^{r} f(x)\,\mathbb{d}x = 2\int_{0}^{r} f(x)\,\mathbb{d}x.
$$
This is a good idea, but it only holds for an even function, i.e., we need $f(-x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [-r, r]$.
If a function is odd, i.e., $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x \in [-r, r]$, we have an even nicer result, namely
$$
\int_{-r}^{r} f(x)\,\mathbb{d}x = 0.
$$
How to repair your solution? Break the integrand into even and odd pieces:
$$
\begin{aligned}
4\pi \int_{-r}^{r} (R - x) \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \,\mathbb{d}x 
&= 4\pi \underbrace{\int_{-r}^{r} R \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \,\mathbb{d}x}_{\text{even}} 
- 4\pi \underbrace{\int_{-r}^{r} x \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \,\mathbb{d}x}_{\text{odd}} \\
&= 8\pi R \int_{0}^{r} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \,\mathbb{d}x - 0 \\[4pt]
&= 8\pi R \bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{4}r^2\bigr) \\[4pt]
&= 2\pi^2 R r^2. 
\end{aligned}
$$
The last integral can be evaluated by simply recognizing it as the area of a quarter circle of radius $r$.

Thank you very much, I didn't see that.

In the second line of your proof, you go from $\int_{-r}^r$ to $2\int_0^r$. That's not true since $R-x$ not equal to $R+x$.

Thank you dude, I'm used to doing that conversion without detailing.
